# Filter data in the reducer or in the component? which is better?

Tags: reactjs, filter, redux, react-redux, reducers

I have this app wherein the home page I load a component that displays a list of movies coming from a local JSON file which I load it in the store in the `App.js` in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle.

And I have another route where I display the single movie details.

Now I have two options, either I create an action that filters the "all movies" list in the reducer and store the single movie in the "initial state" in the reducer, then fire that action in the "SingleMovie" component in its `componentDidMount` function.

Or do I filter all the movies list in the component itself and get the single movie details?

Which is better in terms of performance and best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Put your logic inside the component or in somewhere outside of the component?

A good practice is always keeping your component as skinny as possible. I mean, the component is the one which responsible for the presentation, not the handling application logic.

In your case, you should stick with the option 1: *creating an action that filters the "all movies" list in the reducer and store the single movie in the "initial state" in the reducer, then fire that action in the "SingleMovie" component in its componentDidMount function.*

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to filter the data in reducer and set it to a state and get that particular filtered data inside your component.